# How to solve this cors error i am using Appwrite as for backend when i am trying to signup or perfoming login then it is giving me error

Tags: reactjs, blogs, appwrite

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75eLJ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BNhK.png)
Help me to solve this cors error

I have tried to give permission for all platforms by putting aestrik before localhost but it didnt work and selected a platform web in my appwrite project

Answer (score 0):

You should use port number along with the domain name. So add the `Hostname` as `localhost:{port}`.
Or just use asterisk `*`, but this will not work if you have allow credentials header set.